# Laravel Backpack Permissions From Setup

Tags: php, laravel, rbac, laravel-backpack

I am currently using the [PermissionManager](https://github.com/laravel-backpack/permissionmanager) package for Laravel-Backpack, and I see instructions on how to add permissions through the UI. I need to add roles and permissions from a script or setup (DB Migration maybe), and I see no documentation around this. Would I have to reverse engineer a migration script from a manually created permission (would this even work?) or is there an accepted way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the documentation is [here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager) or [here](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission). Creating new roles&permissions can be done any way you want (migration, script). The tables are very simple, they only have these columns:

- id
- name
- created_at
- updated_at

So the only thing you need to worry about is entering the name of the role/permission.